# Some questions on iOS development

Tags: iphone, ios

I am about to build my first iPhone app.

I have some general questions about the way things should work, and I hope someone could help me out with some information and where I should look.

1. Regarding Push notifications. I understand that the UUID is no more allowed in apple store, and should not be used in apps anymore ? How can I send a specific user a Push notification if I don't have his or her UUID ?
2. Regarding Terms of Use of my app, is there anything covered by apple agreement that should already cover things that I should not worry about once I am on the AppStore?
3. When the app is "Minimized" to the background, How can I still exchange data with my server
   and send a push notification if something seems important on the server side ? (seen on apps like Viber, WhatsApp)

Thanks alot in advance, every piece of information/your own wisdom/link to relevant info would be great help.

Comment: You should probably split this into 3 questions - might be a bit easier to answer then :-).

Comment: This should be split into three separate questions. Also, you have to give more details about your second question. What does your app does or what specific terms are you taking about.

Comment: No offense, but have you looked anything up? This is not Google, and at least questions no. 1 and no. 3 suggest you haven't read a lot about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Use Apple Push Notification Service

" A device token is an opaque identifier of a device that APNs gives to the device when it first connects with it. The device shares the device token with its provider. Thereafter, this token accompanies each notification from the provider. It is the basis for establishing trust that the routing of a particular notification is legitimate."

[Apple Push Notification Service Information Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9)

2 Make a separate question for this with more detail as to what you mean.

3 Use Local Notifications

[Local and Push Notification Information Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Apple's developer website is extremely helpful for these types of questions:  developer.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

1. For PUSH you don't need the UDID. The OS/Framework will give you a per-App-Token which you can then send to your server for knowing your "users".
2. Thats the wrong place to ask about lawyer stuff. :)
3. Viber and WhatsApp are working with push notifications. They are not "really" running in background.
   But you can do Apps that are running in background. Apple allows here VOIP, GPS-Tracking or Music-Listening/Radio-Apps.
   I recommend not to try the ports/conecpts for other app because it might end up by a review-reject fom apple.

Comment: #Jonas Schnelli, What do you mean by ports/concepts ?

Comment: i saw some app's going down while being in the review process that used the Voip Ports (SIP Socket) or pretended to be a Music-In-Background-App but doing other stuff in background. So: yes, there is real multitasking, but no: apple only allows VOIP, GPS-Tracking and Music-in-Background/Radio-Apps.